# How can I access the `document` of a tab that is not active using Chrome Extension API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that runs `popup.js` in the background, every time a tab is done loading([Chrome Tabs API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-TabStatus))it executes a script called `replaceText.js`

Every time a new tab is opened `replaceText.js` is invoked for both **active** and **inactive** tabs. However, when I access `document` it always gets the `document` from the **active** tab. How can I access the `document` from the other tabs?

`popup.js`

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status == 'complete' && tab.active) {
    // console.log(tab.title, document);

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
      file: "replaceText.js"
    }, function() {
    // error
    });
  }
})
```

`replaceText.js`

```
let current_document = document;
// do something with document
```

`manifest.json`

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "a name",
    "description": "a description",
    "version": "1.0",
    "author": "an author",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["popup.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/",
        "https://*/"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Replace `null` with `tabId`.

Comment: @wOxxOm yep that worked, https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) mentioned, I needed to replace `null` with tabId so that the script could know in which tab to run the script, it defaults to the current tab: [tabs.executeScript docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript). I also had to remove the `tab.active` condition so that it could always run.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
      file: "replaceText.js"
    }, function() {
    // error
    });
  }
})
```